# How to jump other page by angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I will use angularjs complete page jump.

I have two page:

1:bootstrap.html

2:config.html

When i click button I hope page jump to config.html from bootstrap.html

My bootstrap.html is like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.controller('myContr',function($scope,$location){

    $scope.selectAll = function(){
       $scope.mySelect = !$scope.mySelect;
    }

    $scope.ngNext = function(path){
      $location.path(path);
    /*  console.log(path);
      var curUrl = $location.absUrl();
      console.log(curUrl);*/

    }

  });
```

```
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="ngNext('config.html')">next</button>
```

When I click the button,the url is:http://localhost/angularjs/bootstrap.html#/config.html, but I hope it like this:http://localhost/angularjs/config.html,Who can help me,thanks

Comment: Have a look at Angular ngRoute API..

Comment: I hope jump from one page to another ,neigher in ng-veiw of one page